# can some one explain me what does self function is used for in numpy

Tags: numpy, self

I was confused how the function self() is used in numpy could you please elobarately explain me?I searched for it in google and SO but did not get a satisfying answer

Comment: Which function self? Please share the code where you found that function. Perhaps, your question is very contextual and you have not provided the context.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of self?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-self?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

there isn't a `self` function in basic Python.

```
In [1072]: self()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1072-588c94f54e14> in <module>()
----> 1 self()

NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

`self` is commonly used in object code to refer to the object itself.  But that would be a function or callable only if the object itself is one.

We can't really answer the question without seeing some of the code where you see this used.